# What is the benefit of buying a special character?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I bought Boba Fett, he came out on the elevator, then just walked through a level and was gone.

This was 5 days ago and i have not seen him since. What was the point of buying him?!

Answer (score 9):

While progressing through the game, random special characters will spawn.  These characters can then trigger special cutscenes depending on the floor you drop them off on.  Buying any special bitzen unlocks them before the game naturally unlocks them from your progression (building floors, etc).

You now will be able to view more information about the unlocked bitzen (in your case, Boba Fett) in the Bitzens page.  To get there, go to  Menu ->  Album -> Select the Bitzens tab (near the bottom).

Boba Fett will be under the first category called Bounty Hunters.   You should also see him show up in your elevator randomly.

EDIT: I actually unlocked him randomly last night.  I got a few screenshots of it.  (Sorry for the huge resolution)

*How I unlocked Boba Fett*

[image]

*Once I found Boba Fett,* **NOTE: "Anticipate their return"**

[image]

*From the bitzen album screen*

[image]